# Laravel failing to parse Arabic lines

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, internationalization, locale, arabic

I am trying to build a website using `Laravel`. I wanted to add `Arabic` language so I created a folder for it and made it the default in the `config.php` file.

Every time I use (`trans`) or (`Lang::get`) to load line from the Arabic file, not only the is not loaded right, but also the whole array is loaded with random letters instead of the Arabic text.

I tried changing the encoding of the file to `UTF-8` or `Unicode` (both the Arabic file and the view) and I got really weird results (Japanes/Chinese letters sometimes).

is there something I am missing?

Comment: Are you getting the output from html ? What is your html charset ? You need to use UTF-8 for every file and UTF-8 for html charset

Comment: I guess I found what I was missing. it was the charset. Thank you @FoxitcL